# DataTable doesn't display any data c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a DataTable and I want to change the first row and column to the elements in RowHeaders and ColumnHeaders which I set in the method 'PopUp'. However, the DataTable is empty when I run the program. Why?

cs-file:

```
namespace myNameSpace
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Interaction logic for PopUp.xaml
            /// </summary>
            public partial class PopUp : Window
            {            


                public string[] RowHeaders { get; set; }
                public string[] ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
                public ResultPopUp(Array[] Result, List<int> Vb1, List<int> Vb)
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    RowHeaders = new string[Vb.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < Vb.Count; i++)
                    {
                        RowHeaders[i] = Vb[i];
                    }

                    ColumnHeaders = new string[Vb1.Count];
                    for (int j = 0; j < Vb1.Count; j++)
                    {
                        ColumnHeaders[j] = Vb1[j];
                    }
                }

            }

                public class MatrixToDataViewConverter : IMultiValueConverter
                {
                    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
                    {
                        var myDataTable = new DataTable();

                        var columns = values[0] as string[];
                        var rows = values[1] as string[];
                        myDataTable.Columns.Add("---"); //Upper left corner
                        foreach (var value in columns)
                        {
                            myDataTable.Columns.Add(value);
                        }


                        foreach (var value in rows)
                        {
                            myDataTable.Rows.Add(value);
                        }

                        return myDataTable.DefaultView;
                    }


                    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }
                }
        }
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ColumnHeaders"/>
                    <Binding Path="RowHeaders"/>
                    <Binding Path="Values"/>
                </MultiBinding>
        </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
      </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger in `Convert`?

Comment: Yes. It stops right after ' myDataTable.Columns.Add("---"); ' and then the window pops up.  Also, values[0] and values[1] are both null. @TimSchmelter

Comment: well if both are null your casts failed. Then you have to cast it to the right type. Use the debugger's quick watch window to see the types of `values[0]` and `values[1]`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please give me an example? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Anna How does it "stop"? Can you describe what you see when it "stops"?

Comment: It skips all the lines below and the window shows. @EdPlunkett

Comment: @Anna No error message? Nothing? It just "skips the lines"? You press F10 and it just skips the rest of the method? I don't think that's true. When it breaks into the debugger, try hovering the mouse over `columns` until a tooltip pops up. Tell me what you see in the tooltip that pops up.

Comment: Nope. Yes, it's very weird. 'columns' is null and values[0] is{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue} . @EdPlunkett

Comment: So it throws a NullReferenceException, and you see that error message in a popup in the debugger.

Comment: Oh wait I got one: System.CastInvalidException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'. @EdPlunkett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out on my own. The problem was that the source binding had no value to provide for conversion. I just had to add `'ElementName="theNameOfMyWindow"'` to `'<Binding Path="..."/>` in my xaml-code and now it works perfectly. But thanks to all of you who tried to help me, I really appreciate it!